# Why does Visual Studio use backing fields for WCF Service References?

Tags: .net, xml, wcf, serialization, datacontract

As many of you will be aware, I can use the `DataContract` attribute to mark a class for serialization into XML in a WCF service.

For example, I can create a `DataContract` thus:

> < DataContract() > Public Class fooClass
>       < Datamember() > Public fooString as String
>       End Class

When I add a service reference to the code that will receive this DataContract, I see that the class generated by the designer has fooString as a public property with a backing field.  My question is, why does the designer use a backing field?  I don't see any reason not to access fooString directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is code design "standard" style used by MS. And is for a good reason to use `properties` instead of `public fields`. Even if on server side you will have data contract like this :

```
[DataContract]
class MyComplexType
{
   [DataMember]
   public int id;
   [DataMember]
   public string name;  
}
```

In client proxy class you will have them as backing fields named something like `idField`, `nameField`...

So it is not connected to  WCF itself it is matter of why to use `properties` instead of `public fields` for which you can easily find guidance.